# How to enter a changing number of columns in a function of calculation using lambda and apply in a panda's dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a new datasat every months with a number of columns who can change.

I want to create a new column in a dataframe with a function like :

```
def calcul(**kwargs):

    [...]

    return result
```

I would create my column like that :

```
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda x: calcul(x['A1'], x['A2'], x['B1']), axis =  1)
```

But i can have this case too :

```
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda x: calcul(x['A1'], x['A2'], x['A3'], x['B1', x['B2']), axis =  1)
```

I try to create a liste of args depending of the data and enter the list with sys.stdout.write(), but it doesn't work

```
liste = ["x[\'A1\']", "x[\'A2\']", "x[\'B1\']"]

df['result'] = df.apply(lambda x: calcul(sys.stdout.write(", ".join(liste))), axis =  1)
```

Comment: I think you mean `*args`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/use-of-args-and-kwargs

Comment: It doesn't work because `df.apply()` is not expecting you to be writing to stdout

Comment: What kind of data are you working with? What is the function meant to do? Some more context would be good.

Comment: The function is complex, its goal is to calculate an accounting provision, this is the reason why i did not enter into details. The variable number of columns depend of the pivot of an other column in the preprocessing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you can replace:

```
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda x: calcul(x['A1'], x['A2'], x['B1']), axis =  1)
```

With:

```
cols = ['A1', 'A2', 'B1']
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda x: calcul(*[x[c] for c in cols]), axis=1)
```

Where cols is your list of columns that changes.

The `*` unpacks the list, so it is equivalent to your original line.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I had try with  df['result'] = df.apply(lambda x: calcul(x[c] for c in cols), axis=1) but it was wrong